# Class property defined as an object that implements interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, interface

I have a set of POCO classes which implement `IConnectable` and `IEntity`.

In one of the classes, `Connection`, I want two properties that are defined as objects that implement `IConnectable`.

```
    public interface IConnectable
{
 string Name { get; set; }
 string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And my connection class

```
    public partial class Connection : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public T<IConnectable> From { get; set; }
    public T<IConnectable> To { get; set; }
    public ConnectionType Type { get; set; }
    public double Affinity { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can't use generic objects are properties -- so is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You mean you simply want `public IConnectable From { get; set; }` or am I reading the question wrong?

Comment: Does that not imply the property is an an interface? If property type is an interface can I pass it an object that implements that interface?

Comment: @MattFoxxDuncan Yes, you most certainly can.  That's...kinda the point actually.

Comment: Well then I guess i've got my wires crossed! That makes sense -- I'm not sure why this was confusing me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely appropriate to just not have generics at all :

```
public partial class Connection : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IConnectable From { get; set; }
    public IConnectable To { get; set; }
    public ConnectionType Type { get; set; }
    public double Affinity { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

If it's important that instances of `Connection` return types of something more derived then you'll need to make the whole class generic:

```
public partial class Connection<T> : IEntity
    where T : IConnectable 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public T From { get; set; }
    public T To { get; set; }
    public ConnectionType Type { get; set; }
    public double Affinity { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to be able to have two different `IConnectable` types for the two properties, then you need to generic parameters:

```
public partial class Connection<TFrom, TTo> : IEntity
    where TFrom : IConnectable 
    where TTo : IConnectable 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TFrom From { get; set; }
    public TTo To { get; set; }
    public ConnectionType Type { get; set; }
    public double Affinity { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```